# TypeError:Cannot read property hub of undefined

Tags: javascript, signalr

I am getting the exception when run on signalr javascript client..

**TypeError:Cannot read property hub of undefined**

Please help me to solve this exception.. Thank you..

My Javascript file is...

```
<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        try
        {
            alert("inside function");
            //Set the hubs URL for the connection

            $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.myHub;
            alert(chat);
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.

            // Start the connection.


            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                alert("Connection succeeded");
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("Connection failed");
            });


        }
        catch (err) {
            alert("Error:" + err);

        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Can you console.log `$.connection` and see if its defined?

Comment: how do i know whether it is defined or not.. where i go to defined the connection.?

Comment: I am trying to connect signalr selfhost server and javascript client.. how to define $.connection